# How to proof: Closure of set is equal to intersection of sets

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

I know that
$$\overline{A} = \bigcap_{r>0}[A+S(0,r)].$$
I need to proof that
$$\overline{A} = \bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}[A+S(0,2^{-n})].$$
I already have shown
$$\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}[A+S(0,2^{-n})] \subset \overline{A}.$$
How to show that
$$\overline{A} \subset \bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}[A+S(0,2^{-n})]?$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: That is the easy direction. Use $\bigcap\mathcal A\subseteq\bigcap\mathcal B$ whenever $\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal A$.

Comment: Ok. I know this property, but I want to do this proof in different way. I took $x \in \overline{A}$ so there exists r>0 such that $x\in A + S(0,r)$... and what now?..